# Make Visual Studio's Find in Files default to the project directory?

Tags: visual-studio, findinfiles

I have many different branches/checkouts of the same project code on my development machine. Each one is virtually the same except for various maintenance bug fixes or improvements I'm working on within each project.

The problem comes when I use Find in Files inside Visual Studio to search through my code. VS2005 stores the last search directory that was used in its Find in Files dialog ... this may or may not be the project directory I'm working on. Since my projects are so similar, it's easy to accidentally search through a similar project, change some code, and only realize later that I've edited the wrong project. (Argh!!)

Is there a way to make VS default its Find in Files search to the project directory? Obviously a properties setting would be wonderful, but an add-in would be fine too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This drives me nuts too.  But in "Look In:" dropdown on the find in files dlg you will find items for Solution and project.  I think that should work for you.

Answer (score -1):

In VS2008, with no files open, when I select 'Current Project' it searches whatever project is currently selected in the Solution Explorer. When I switch between files in different projects, it correctly searches the project of the currently selected file. I don't see any options for changing this behavior.